# implemented title attributed for row in picker view did not change the font?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I tried to change the font of the title in my picker view, **but for some reason I could not. I can change the color of the title, but the font remains intact?**

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let attrTitle = NSAttributedString(string: splitPickerSource[row], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 17.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray])
        return attrTitle
    }
```

Alternatively I can implement `viewForRow` delegate method for the `UIPickerView` and add a new label from there.

Some debugging message as maddy suggested when try to printout `attrTitle`

```
Share Bill With{ NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.117647 0.117647 0.117647 1"; NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb5f8d14080> font-family: \"Avenir-Heavy\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
```

Anyone has any idea about this situation and why can't I modify the font in
`attributedTitleForRow` delegate method?

Comment: Have you verified that this delegate method is being called? Have you looked at the value of `attrTitle` in the debugger to make sure it looks correct?

Comment: yes, I can change the color, so it's being called.

Comment: I didn't look at it at the debugger, how can I verify that? Just set a breakpoint, and it said `ObjectiveC.NSObject NSObject `

Comment: Yes, set a breakpoint on the `return attrTitle` line.

Comment: How can you tell whether the `attrTitle` valid or not, because the only information it contains is the address for the object?

Comment: Right-click on `attrTitle` and choose `print value` (or something like that). The value of the variable will be shown in the console.

Comment: I got something like this Printing description of attrTitle:
▿ Optional<NSAttributedString>
Printing description of attrTitle.some:
`Share Bill With{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.117647 0.117647 0.117647 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb5f8d14080> font-family: \"Avenir-Heavy\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";`

Comment: That looks right. Your attributed string has the text `Share Bill With` and that text has the specified font and color. Perhaps the picker replaces the font when it displays the string.

Comment: Yes, it seems strange. It looks like it uses the system font

Answer (score 1):

You have made a typo that's why it is not working. It should be

```
    let attrTitle = NSAttributedString(string: splitPickerSource[row], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 17.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray])
```

I removed the extra size: 14 after NSFontAttributeName was supposed to end.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed, but that's not the reason though.

Comment: Have you checked that the font is on your system correctly? Add this code in a playground which will give you all fonts  in the console: for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
{
    print("\(family)")
    for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    {
        print("\(names)")
    }
}    check if Avenir-Heavy is there

Comment: @gwinyai It must be a valid font because there is a `!` after `UIFont(...)`. If there was no such font that would cause a fatal crash due to force unwrapping a nil.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
//MARK: Setting picker select label size

    /**
     Called by Picker to To add customized text to fit size
     - parameter pickerView: The picker view requesting the data.
     - parameter row: Index of row
     - parameter component: component Index
     */

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {        
        let pickerLabel = UILabel() //get picker label that come

        pickerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //Wrapping if needed

        pickerLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //So it comes to single line 

        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white //setting colour 

        self.currentValue = NamesStringArray[row] //Array with Titles

        let data = NamesStringArray[row] //Taking Index Title

        let title = NSAttributedString(string: data, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 40.0)!]) //here add attributes

        pickerLabel.attributedText = title //setting attributed text as title

        pickerLabel.sizeToFit() //Size to fit //If needed

        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true //if needed

        return pickerLabel //return value

    }
```

[image]