# Why is picker view not displaying attributed string?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, nsattributedstring

There is one post on stack overflow already addressing this problem, but it did not solve the problem, it worked around it. [implemented title attributed for row in picker view did not change the font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876229/implemented-title-attributed-for-row-in-picker-view-did-not-change-the-font)

Why is the callback `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)` not showing the correct font.

Here is my code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {  

    if component == 0 {  
        print(keysDataSource[row])  
        return keysDataSource[row]  
    } else {  
        print(chordsDataSource[row])  
        return chordsDataSource[row]  
    }  

}
```

Here is the results in the debug window showing the result of the print statement when that callback function is called:

```
vi{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x113d55700> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 30.00pt";
}
```

The problem is apparent in the screenshot. The attributes do not all show. The baseline offset attribute shows, but none of the font attributes show. It shows a system font instead. Notice the b and the L, which are supposed to show as a musical flat symbol and a musical diminished symbol respectively.

[image: screenshot picker view]

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Brower

use both method for title `cause picker view is get first titleForRow.

use code like this.

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       return pickerViewObj.keys[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: pickerViewObj.keys[row], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
        return attributedString
    }
```

OR

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"

    return pickerLabel
}
```

I hope this code will be work.

Comment: I get the same results as the original problem.

Comment: Okay user `viewForRow` method.

Comment: Yes. That's what the other stackoverflow post says. That must be all I can do if I don't get another answer.